# How to build a "skype" window (standing connection)

Tags: skype, webcam, conferencing

I'm looking to build a sort of window between two offices separated by... oh, I don't know, a couple of oceans, mountain ranges etc...

The idea is to keep a team connected by placing an always-on bi-directional video conference solution in a common room at each of the two office buildings. Somewhere where people would walk past a couple of times a day and could spontaneously gather to chat.

I'm curious... has this been done before? What technology should I use?

- I guess I'll need two screens
- maybe computers? Or are there dedicated machines?
- Webcams? (I believe it will need to be wide-angle)
- Microphones?
- What software? Custom? I meen... skype won't stay connected all the time, right?

I've used the Logitech ConferenceCam before, hooked up to an iMac - that worked for a skype workstation setting for meetings. I just think there has to be something better out there.

**EDIT**: It seems something like a [Cisco TelePresence SX10 Quick Set](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collaboration-endpoints/telepresence-sx10-quick-set/index.html) might work. Has anyone tried that?

Comment: Did you look at just a kind of security camera's?

Comment: Coca-Cola did this in [2013](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2013/05/20/coca-cola-ad-says-coke-vending-machines-can-soothe-india-pakistan-tensions/) to unite India and Pakistan.